# Why strings are permitted while arrays are not in this code?

Tags: c, string, argument-passing

```
#include<stdio.h>
void function1(){}
int main(void)
{
  function1(1,0.45,'b',"I am trying");
  function1();
  return 0;
}
```

this compiles nicely.
But the below is showing

> Error: use arr in function1 first....

Note that I am using `code::blocks` IDE and saved that file with .c extension.

```
#include<stdio.h>
void function1(){}
int main(void)
{
   function1(1,0.45,'b',"I am trying",arr[12]);
   function1();
   return 0;
}
```

sorry I made a mistake calling it an array. But `{1,2,3,4}` this is an array you will agree to it ..but this also does not work. Is it a bug or what ?

Comment: Where is `arr` declared?

Comment: That's not an array...

Comment: Note: There is no proper prototype for `function1`. Enable warnings.

Comment: GCC default compilation flags permit C90 syntax. Empty parens indicates "takes an unspecified fixed number of arguments".

Comment: I was surprised to see that the first code block even compiled cleanly with -Wall, much less run.  I knew that an empty argument list in a function prototype means the function takes an unknown number of arguments, but I didn't know that extended to the actual function definition as well.

Comment: @dbush:  It's a throwback to K&R 1.  Prototypes were introduced in K&R 2, ANSI C ('86) but the old syntax was supported for backward compatibility.  Backward is a good name for it ....

Comment: @cdarke: The ANSI C standard was published in 1989 (and republished by ISO in 1990).

Comment: You've *defined* `function` with no parameters, but you've *declared* that it takes a fixed but unspecified number and type(s) of arguments. Passing arguments to it is invalid, but the compiler is not required to diagnose the error; the behavior is undefined. The ability to do this is an unfortunate historical throwback. Change the definition to `void function1(void) { }`, and the compiler will diagnose the error.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Typo, yes 1989.  You almost gave me a shock, I mis-read your first name as Ken. :-)

Comment: @cdarke: I think that makes three times I've been mistaken for him. 8-)}

Comment: @jxh: "GCC default compilation flags permit C90 syntax". 1) not just the syntax, but also the semantics (There have been some changes from C90 to C99). 2) No, it defaults to support a standard plus gnu-extensions. 3) Depends: since 5.1 it is `gnu11`.

Comment: @Olaf: I apologize for the impreciseness of my comment. I  didn't realize you cared that much, but kudos to you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the second case,

```
 function1(1,0.45,'b',"I am trying",arr[12]);
```

`arr[12]` is a variable, and `arr` itself is not defined, least being as an array.

In C, you need to define a variable before using it.

FWIW,

```
function1(1,0.45,'b',"I am trying");
```

works, because

- `1` is an `int` literal
- `0.45` is a `double` literal
- `'b'` is a `char` literal
- **`"I am trying"` is a string literal**

and none of them is a *variable*.

Comment: fine ...as string passing is not a compilation error so array should not be right ??? ok i agree that i made a mistake ...{1,2,3,4} this is also an array right.instead of arr put this ...then also compilation error

Comment: @DebashishSaha `{1,2,3,4}` is an initializer list, not an array all by itself.

Comment: there is 2 way to define an array 
1.sijmply put all in braces
  2.define variable like int arr[10]

Comment: @DebashishSaha I would recommend to stop reading the book at once.

Comment: @DebashishSaha FWIW, with the help of compound literals, over and above c99, `{1,2,3,4}` can be interpreted as an array, but that's a different story altogether.

Comment: if it can be interpreted as an array why compilation error  occurred ?

Comment: string is also a typical character array ...why it does not show any compilation error thats what my question is

Comment: @DebashishSaha there is a basic difference between a variable and a literal, read up about that first, all your question will most likely get answer there.

Comment: my dear if string literal can be permitted then why array literal cant be ??? 
 "I am trying" it is accepted but {1,2,3,4} this isn't why ?????

Comment: @DebashishSaha can you point me first where did you find "array literal"?

Comment: so the conclusion is as array literals does not exist thats why compilation error has occurred isn't it ??

Comment: @DebashishSaha no, it's not. the answer is the third line in my answer.